# help requested understanding Java Reflection --> Android ParcelableContainer

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I'm, playing with the Android framework and try to get my mind deeper into Java. For This I read about Javas Generics and the Reflection API, while I'm not understanding it really. 
Because I'm a lazy Dev ;) I tried to write an 'Parcelable-Container' in which I can put ANY Object I wish to get it Parcelable without the need to implement this for every Object again using methods of Java Reflection.

I write a test method like these:

```
public <T> void writeClassInformations(T t){
        Class c = t.getClass();

        System.out.println("DeclaredFields: ");
        for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()){
            System.out.println(f.toGenericString());
        }
        System.out.println("Fields: ");
        for (Field f: c.getFields()){
            System.out.println(f.toGenericString());
        }
}
```

How can I get every member even if they are Objects or private Superclass members?
And another Question: The output is like this:

*public int hello.test.Testclass.myID*

how I get the value of 'myID'?

---

ADD:
I'm running in serious problems now. The Interface of Parcelable.Creator forces me to write a statement like: `public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = 
        new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableBox<?>>()`
Can I use `?` somehow? Normally I use a constructor like `ParcelableBox(E object)`. While it seems to me that I can't use Object methods on `?` I even cannot pass it into a class variable like

```
public ParcelableBox<?> createFromParcel(Parcel source){  
  ...
  return new ParcelableBox<?>(); 
}
```

or `? myClass` to use Reflection on it. Is this the end of javas reflection power? How can I get Class of `?`

Comment: To answer your second question -- use Field.get(), passing in the instance object (t).

Comment: and which field is it returning if I have more than one member in it?

Comment: field.get(object, parameters...).  

You get the value for that field that you call "get" from, and you get the value from the object you pass in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection should be used sparingly, or not at all if it can be avoided, and especially not as a way to hack around good design principles. That being said, it can also be useful in certain situations ...

`getDeclaredFields` can return all types of fields while `getFields` only returns fields marked public.

The reason your test returns the same thing is that you're using `getDeclaredFields` in both statements.

---

`how I get the value of 'myID'`

You can only do that by operating on an instance of a class. E.g.,

```
T t = ...
Field field = t.getClass().getDeclaredField("myID");
field.setAccessible(true);
String value = (String) field.get(t);
```

Comment: Thx, Youre are right with everything you said. But as I wrote it is only for testing and learning purposes.